Пустое пространство в ListBox при использовании UniformDataGrid
Что можно сделать, чтобы после элементов в ListBox не было пустого пространства(там остается пространства на три строки). Мне нужно использовать UnifromDataGrid, чтобы элементы размещались равномерно.
        <ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollViewerProducts" Grid.Row="1" ScrollChanged="ScrollViewer_ScrollChanged">
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Products}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                 ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Classes="catalog">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid ></UniformGrid>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="250" Width="287">
                        <Border ClipToBounds="True">
                            <asyncImageLoader:AdvancedImage Stretch="UniformToFill"
                                Source="{Binding Image, Converter={StaticResource imageConv},TargetNullValue='/Assets/noimage.png'}" Name="imgProduct"></asyncImageLoader:AdvancedImage>
                        </Border>
                        <Border ClipToBounds="True" IsVisible="{Binding #imgProduct.IsLoading, FallbackValue=True}">
                            <ProgressBar Classes="loading"></ProgressBar>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                    <TextBlock TextAlignment="Center" Height="50" Margin="0,10,0,0"
                               FontWeight="Bold"  TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"
                               FontSize="16" Classes="HeaderProduct" TextWrapping="Wrap"
                               Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding PriceOfSale, StringFormat='{}{0} ₽'}"
                                       FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="18"></TextBlock>
                    <Button Classes="Login" Margin="5"
                        Command="{Binding $parent[UserControl].DataContext.EditProductCommand}"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding ProductId}">Редактировать</Button>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>  
</ScrollViewer>


